# Inserting a record only it does not exists in a database without any data

Tags: sql, ms-access, vbscript, vba

I am trying to code within VBScript so that it adds the current record into an Access database. It only works if there is data within the database but when there isn't any data, it will not work.

```vb
If (ReportFile.AtEndofStream = False) Then
    LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, vbTab)
    con.Execute _
        "INSERT INTO SalesOrder ( SONo )" & _
        " SELECT DISTINCT ('" & LineItems(0) & "')" & _
        " FROM SalesOrder" & _
        " WHERE ((((Select Count(SONo) FROM SalesOrder WHERE SalesOrder.SONo = '" & LineItems(0) & "'))=0));"
End If
```

Comment: Define "will not work".

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details as requested. See: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to be using EXISTS in the WHERE clause, and you shouldn't be selecting from the SalesOrder table before the WHERE clause, because the table is empty and will return no rows.
I presume that you have used DISTINCT because when SalesOrder had more than one row, you would be inserting the same LineItems(0) value for each row, causing a primary key violation:

This is what I did in Management Studio:

```
Create Table SalesOrder (SONo int Primary Key)
go
INSERT INTO SalesOrder ( SONo )
select SONo
from (select SONo = 2) a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select 1 FROM SalesOrder WHERE SalesOrder.SONo = a.SONo)
go
```

So I think your vbscript code should be:

```
If (ReportFile.AtEndofStream = False) Then
    LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, vbTab)
    con.Execute _
        "INSERT INTO SalesOrder ( SONo )" & _
        " SELECT  (select SONo = '" & LineItems(0) & "') a" & _
        " WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select 1 FROM SalesOrder " & _ 
        "                   WHERE SalesOrder.SONo = a.SONo);"
End If
```